# How to move sound from left to right of earphones in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2, avfoundation

I am making an app for blind people with swift and I can play sound only on the right headphone or only on the left by using the pan property like this:

```
@IBAction func right(sender: UIButton) {
    player.pan = 1.0 //right headphone
}


@IBAction func left(sender: UIButton) {
    player.pan = -1.0 //left headphone

}
```

But I need to start playing sound in the right and then move it to the left headphone, how can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you look into one of many tutorials of how to make use of `AVAudioPlayer` from `AVFoundation`, see [e.g. this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114298/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-5-making-it-beautiful). Also, possibly you could use an `UISlider` rather than two buttons, and let the value of the slider control the value of the `.pan` property of your player (map slider span -> [-1, 1]).

Comment: The slider idea is a good one, but I need to move sound automatically

Comment: Assuming that the sound you're trying to create is a simple tone (not panning music) then rather than using AVAudioPlayer, you could look at OpenAL instead - it's more focussed on games, but seems like it may be a better fit to your use case. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW3

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the panning should be based on, but if you simply want it to move over time, you could just use a timer to update it.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update() {
    if player.pan == -1.0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }

    player.pan -= 0.1
}
```